# using [NSOperationQueue mainQueue] in XCTests

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, nsoperationqueue, xctest

I'm testing a part of my code using using XCTest that also adds NSOperations on the main queue.
It looks like this:

`[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationAsBlock:^{
 // some code happens here
}];`

The code runs when running the app on a device or in the simulator but doesn't run at all when running the unit test (I can't get to the debug point on the first line of the block).

calling:

`[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];`

doesn't help as well.

Any suggestions? I think i'm missing some code to initialise the queue.

*** EDIT ***

Thanks for your answers, I added my resulting code for completeness:

```
// add as many operations as you'd like to the mainQueue here
__block BOOL continueCondition = YES;
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
    // this should be the last operation
    continueCondition = NO;
}];
while (continueCondition)  {
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
} // continue your test here
```

This works because the mainQueue is guaranteed to be non-concurrent so the last operation that's added will be the last one executed - this way you don't even have to change your code to stop the test loop.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463733/objective-c-unit-testing-dispatch-async-block

Comment: Re; your edit to Kazuki's answer (which I see you have changed your mind on). If you like you use that content to add your own answer including the code you used, why it worked etc

Comment: Ideally such an answer would go in an answer box however, rather than in the question itself; see the "answer your own question" button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as [IOS -NSRunLoop in XCTest: How Do I Get A Run Loop to Work in A Unit Test?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19522898/629118)

Also, [aquarius / XCTestCase+MNAsynchronousTestCase.h](https://gist.github.com/aquarius/6112410) is helpful for it.